# QGIS Fetch Python Plugins Crash

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I am using QGIS v1.6 on Ubuntu 10.10.

When I use the Fetch Python Plugins menu item QGIS crashes. If I run from the terminal with sudo I get the following error:

Segmentation Fault

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have this problem on 2 installs of Ubuntu on 2 different computers.

Comment: I remember this from the qgis-user forum. I don't see a solution, :( ,but maybe a contact and other reading will hook you up. HTH  http://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg05732.html   I thought I remembered a thread that respoded with a solution, It seemed like renaming a file and restarting qgis was how to fix, but it has been quite a while and I was only reading.

Comment: Unfortunately non of these things worked. Reinstalling ubuntu had worked though. Maybe it is something to do with the fact I upgraded from 10.04 and didn't do a fresh install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python library is probably out of sync with the python library the QGIS plugin was built on. This has been an ongoing issue and can get me more then a little irritated.
Here is what I finally did:

Use QGIS from experimental. Add the nightly build to your sources in apt usually fixes this issue, but puts you on the bleeding edge, not recommended for production work. 
http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Download#Trunk_4 The python version and Qgis version seem to stay in sync this way.

Comment: I have added QGIS the way you suggest from experimental, but this still causes the segmentation error. I cannot get any plugins from the repositories due to this error.